# Is there a way to know if a ruby method has been redefined?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I want to know if a method on a class gets redefined.

use case: in version 1 of ruby-clock, defining a method on an object was part of the API. In version 2, doing so will break behavior, and a different API should be used.

what I ended up doing: https://github.com/jjb/ruby-clock/pull/28/files

---

The best would be if I could use some sort of metaprogramming to notice when it happens.:

```rb
# this is example code which does not work
class MyClass
  def my_method
    puts "hello"
  end

  # this is not real! it's an example of what i hope is somehow possible
  def self.method_defined(m, *args, &block)
    if :my_method == m
      raise "you should not redefine my_method!"
    end
  end
end
```

Also acceptable would be if I could check back later and see if it has changed.

```rb
# this is example code which does not work
class MyClass
  def my_method
    puts "hello"
  end

  @@my_method_object_id = get_method_object_id(:my_method)
end

# later, when app initialization is done, check if the user redefined the method
# this is not real! it's an example of what i hope is somehow possible
def self.method_defined(m, *args, &block)
  if MyClass.get_method_object_id(:my_method) != MyClass.my_method_object_id
    raise "you should not redefine my_method!"
  end
end
```

n.b. that `MyClass.method(:my_method)` is a real thing in ruby, but it always produces a new object.

Comment: There's no built-in callback for this. So, what real-world problem are you trying to solve for with this? It seems like an X/Y problem. If you don't want to overwrite the original methods, why not just alias them and work on the copies, or use refinements?

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs I've now added info about my use case to the top of the question

Comment: I don't see this as an X-Y problem. The OP simply wants to know if what is being ask is possible. There are plenty of SO questions that ask if something can be done even when there is a another way to achieve the same result that is much easier. Attempting to solve the problem the hard way may have educational value, however. For example, I can think of complex regular expressions I have  constructed that no one in their right mind would consider using (in part because of the difficulty of testing), yet I have learned things about regular expressions that have been useful in other contexts.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds pretty much like XY problem. I don't think you should go this way - if you find yourself fighting with the Ruby object model, you most probably picked the wrong tool for the job.

But for the sake of completeness... There are a couple of callbacks in `Module` that can help with the ideas as crazy as this one. In particular, there is `Module#method_added` which is called each time some instance method is defined. So we can do smth. like this (very dirty example):

```
class C
  @foo_counter = 0

  def self.method_added(name) 
    if name == :foo
      @foo_counter += 1
      if @foo_counter > 1
        raise "Don't redefine foo!"
      end
    end  
  end  
  
  def foo
    "foo"
  end  
end
```

now if one tries to open `C` and redefine `foo` the following happens (pry session as an example):

```
pry(main)> class C
pry(main)*   def foo
pry(main)*     "bar"
pry(main)*   end  
pry(main)* end

RuntimeError: Don't redefine foo!
```

So you *can* do what you want to (to some extent - it's Ruby, so what stops one from redefining the annoying hook first? :)), but please don't. You'll get nothing but troubles...

Comment: I've now added info about my use case to the top of the question

Comment: @JohnBachir I briefly checked: it seems that `schedule` is `Rufus::Scheduler.singleton`, right? Can't you just create a simple almost transparent wrapper object that would forward everything (but `around_trigger`) to rufus scheduler as is, and for  `around_trigger` it prints the warning  (or raise an error - what reaction you need) before delegating?

Comment: i need the warning when around_trigger is defined, not when it is invoked, so i can't use method_missing, if that is what you mean by a wrapper

Answer (score 0):

You could use the callback [BasicObject#singleton_method_added](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-singleton_method_added).

```
class C
  @class_methods = []

  def self.singleton_method_added(m)
    puts "Method #{m} was just redefined" if @class_methods.include?(m)
    @class_methods << m
  end

  def self.c
    puts 'hi'
  end
end
```

```
C.c
  #=> "hi"
```

```
class C
  def self.c
    puts 'ho'
  end
end
Method c was just redefined
```

```
C.c #=> "ho"
```

Comment: I just noticed my answer is similar to @Konstantin's (we even named the class the same), but I think it's sufficiently different that I will let it stand.

Comment: This one fits better the updated task definition :)